# Why the coturn server returning 401: Unauthorized

Tags: ubuntu, realm, coturn

i have installed a Coturn server on ubunto 16
currently i'm checking it with

```
function checkTURNServer(turnConfig, timeout){ 

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(promiseResolved) return;
        resolve(false);
        promiseResolved = true;
    }, timeout || 5000);

    var promiseResolved = false
      , myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
      , pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers:[turnConfig]})
      , noop = function(){};
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp){
      if(sdp.sdp.indexOf('typ relay') > -1){ // sometimes sdp contains the ice candidates...
        promiseResolved = true;
        resolve(true);
      }
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
      if(promiseResolved || !ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !(ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ relay')>-1))  return;
      promiseResolved = true;
      resolve(true);
    };
  });   
}

const USERNAME="user"
const PASSWORD="password"
const PORT=3478
const IP="my_Coturn_server_ip" // you will have to change this

console.log('TURN server reachable on TCP?', await checkTURNServer( {
    url: `turn:${IP}:${PORT}?transport=tcp`,
    username: USERNAME,
    credential: PASSWORD,
}))

console.log('TURN server reachable on UDP?', await checkTURNServer( {
    url: `turn:${IP}:${PORT}?transport=udp`,
    username: USERNAME,
    credential: PASSWORD,
}))
```

every time i try to check i get this in the server

14: session 001000000000000001: realm  user <>: incoming packet BINDING process                                                                              ed, success
14: session 001000000000000001: realm  user <>: incoming packet message process                                                                              ed, error 401: Unauthorized
14: IPv4. Local relay addr: my_Coturn_server_ip:57906
14: session 001000000000000001: new, realm=, username=, lifetime=600
14: session 001000000000000001: realm  user : incoming packet ALLOCATE pr                                                                              ocessed, success
24: session 000000000000000001: realm  user : incoming packet BINDING pro                                                                              cessed, success

why it is returning 401 ?
how i can open the server to public without authentication ?

Answer (score 3):

The 401 is just part of the digest authentication: the first Allocate request is sent by the client without authentication data.

The server challenges the Allocate Request with a 401, providing a realm and nonce.

The client then uses the realm, nonce, username and password to compute the authentication key and send again the Allocate Request, which gets an Allocate Success Response.

The full process is explained in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8656

In general TURN servers are not open to public usage without authentication because their usage is resource intensive and can become very expensive.